# php preg_replace everything in between specific html comment tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've checked other answers but can't seem to do the following. Please help someone :)

I want to remove everything in between and including specific html comments

**HTML:**

```
Some HTML that must stay
<!-- START IF USER_ID -->
some html that must go
<!-- END IF USER_ID -->
Some more HTML that's gotta stay
<!-- START IF USER_ID -->
this also needs to go
<!-- END IF USER_ID -->
```

So everything in between `<!-- START IF USER_ID -->` and `<!-- END IF USER_ID -->` and the comments itself needs to go

**My preg_replace pattern** (which is obviously wrong):

```
"/<!-- START IF USER_ID -->.*?<!-- END IF USER_ID -->/"
```

**Result should be**

```
Some HTML that must stay
Some more HTML that's gotta stay
```

Thanks for checking and for the answers in advance :)

Comment: maybe it can help http://www.adminhelpline.com/en/free-scripts/php/string/how-to-replace-text-between-2-tags-with-php

Comment: @mlwacosmos Thanks man. Would have accepted yours as the answer. +1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks @mlwacosmos - Using the link you provided.

Achieved with:

```
$startPoint = '<!-- START IF USER_ID -->';
$endPoint = '<!-- END IF USER_ID -->';
$result = preg_replace('#('.preg_quote($startPoint).')(.*)('.preg_quote($endPoint).')#siU', '', $html);
```

Comment: How to do this but stop at the first $endpoint ? If you have  xxx $start yyy $end zzz $end. I dont wanna delete the zzz because there is an enpoint before.

Comment: Thanks @neoteknic never realised this. Answer modified to include non-greedy modifier `U` which stops at the first one then continues onwards.

Answer (score 3):

That regex looks fine. Use an `m` modifier to make the dot match newlines:

```
"/<!-- START IF USER_ID -->.*?<!-- END IF USER_ID -->/m"
```

Alternatively, you could use `[\s\S]` as a substitute:

```
"/<!-- START IF USER_ID -->[\s\S]*?<!-- END IF USER_ID -->/"
```