# Remove CSS inside comments using PHP

Tags: php, regex

Let's say I have a string like this:

```
$css = '.class {
    color: red;
}

/* Start Comment */
.replace {
    content: "me";
}
/* End Comment */';
```

How can I remove everything inside the comment, including the comment itself?

I want this result:

```
.class {
    color: red;
}
```

I've tried something like this, but it doesn't do it:

```
$css = preg_replace( '#(/* Start Comment */).*?(/* End Comment */)#', '', $css );
```

I've also tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13824617/2391422

Am I missing something ridiculously obvious here?

Really appreciate any feedback - regex is something I need to study further.

Comment: `*` is a special character, you have to escape it if you want to match a literal `*`. `.` doesn't match the newline character `\n` by default. To allow it to match the newline character too, you have to use the `s` modifier.

Comment: Try escaping `/` and `*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this code to work by adding the DOTALL-modifier `s`
http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

```
$css = preg_replace( '#(/\\* Start Comment \\*/).*?(/\\* End Comment \\*/)#s', '', $css );
```

Additionally, the `*` should be escaped to get the desired effect. The `/` are fine as you are using another delimiter.

Comment: /\/\*.+;/s also matches your string

Comment: You don't have to use two backslashes to escape the `*` only one suffice. Note that you can also use the `\Q...\E` feature for long literal parts.

Comment: It works without but it is cleaner to always escape the backslash, even in single quotes. Besides single quotes itself the only thing to manually escape.